# What are the most common and widely used plugins for Hudson, specially for Continuous Integration of ASP.NET Web Apps?

Tags: asp.net, continuous-integration, build-automation, hudson, hudson-plugins

I searched around stackoverflow and could not find any relevant questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good primer for using Hudson with .Net:

http://redsolo.blogspot.com/2008/04/guide-to-building-net-projects-using.html

The plugins used are MSBuild, NUnit, Violations (for FXCop integration), Open Tasks.  NAnt is another commonly used plugin if you already have your build scripts taking advantage of it.

Here is an example using asp.net.  They modded up their own FtpTask plugin to use for deployment:

http://blogs.freshlogicstudios.com/Posts/View.aspx?Id=87a1c0f7-a75e-4f1a-8d3a-6c52c6ad9f46